# Why am I getting empty links in Json response as part of the embedded resources?

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am trying to populate JSON response which includes embedded resources using Spring Hateoas framework.But I am getting empty "links" as part of my Json response. Unable to figure which part/module of the function is populating empty JSON field.

JSON class is extending Spring "Resource Support" class?

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: please follow this [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so that we can understand your question clearly and we can help you in a better way.